# What configuration or variable caused Aritfactory to replace "-SNAPSHOT" with timestamp

Tags: maven, azure-devops, artifactory

Current CI pipeline can push artifact to Artifactory. I can see one of the `snapshot` artifact was built with suffix `-SNAPSHOT` like

```
my.first.app-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

across the pipeline, until it uploaded to Artifactory that the file name changed to

```
my.first.app-0.0.1-20211007.010722-1.jar
```

However there is another application

```
my.second.app-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

was processed by the same pipeline and after uploaded to Artifactory the file name stayed the same

```
my.second.app-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So just wondering what variable caused the difference in behavior. My goald is to avoid this timestamp however I have no control in Artifactory settings and based on above observation, seems not an issue with repository level settings.

Comment: What is the problem with the timestamp because you reference it via `-SNAPSHOT` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise. Correct it's referred by unique filename preferably, otherwise has to use wildcard or regular expression for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is a maven feature and not related to artifactory.

See a similar question on this: [Why the snapshot name always has date in its jar file name ? How to remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920536/why-the-snapshot-name-always-has-date-in-its-jar-file-name-how-to-remove-it)

Comment: Thank you. If this is a maven feature but running through a pipeline (like Azure DevOps), how the different behavior is triggered? Is it through `pom.xml`? I see the answer from other thread using mvn deploy with options however this command is not available through the pipeline

Comment: I assume each one of these tools has a way to control the maven properties. It might also be controlled in the pom.xml. Need to look into the docs of the tool and maven.